# Run node.js with --debug argument

Tags: node.js

When I run node like this:

```
node some.js --debug=6776
```

Debugger is not started, however if I run it like that:

```
node --debug=6776 some.js
debugger listening on port 6776
```

Debugger is started. Why so? Is the order of arguments important?

Comment: In first one you pass `--debug=6776` as an argument to your script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in `man node`.

```
 SYNOPSIS
        node [ -v ] [ --debug | --debug-brk ] [ --v8-options ]
             [ -e command | script.js ] [ arguments ]
```

`node some.js --debug=6776` means run `some.js` (with node) with the argument `--debug=6776`

`node --debug=6776 some.js` means run node with the two arguments `--debug=6776` and `some.js`

Comment: thanks, I understand now, but I can find link to the docs that shows that